# odeint returns wrong results for an ODE including descrete function

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I'm trying to model the ODE:

> [image]

I implemented:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = 1
k = 1
M = 0.1
b = 1
Fmax = 1
def dXdt(X,t):
    return [X[1], - b * X[1] / m - k * X[0] / m - M * np.sign(X[1]) / m + Fmax / m ]

X0 = [1, 2]
ts = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
Xs = odeint(dXdt, X0, ts)
plt.plot(ts, Xs[:, 0])
```

resulting:

> [image]

which contradicts what I get from Modelica (OpenModelica):

```
model model1
//constants
  parameter Real m = 1;
  parameter Real k = 1;
  parameter Real b = 1;
  parameter Real M = 0.1;
  parameter Real Fmax = 1;
//variables
  Real x, v, a;
initial equation
  x = 1;
  v = 2;
equation
  v = der(x);
  a = der(v);
  m * a + b * v + k * x + M * sign(v) = Fmax;
end model1;
```

> [image]

I would appreciate if you could help me know where is my mistake and how I can solve it.

Comment: Your solution ends at about t=4.7880 with X[0]=0.94535. There exists no solution after that point, the solver enters an undefined sliding mode. If you restrict the time in odeint to the same interval [0,1] you should get the same solution as modelica, as there are no discontinuities on that interval.

Comment: @LutzL I edited the step size and end time to make sure they are same for both Modelica and Python. Now I see that Python returns [random results](https://imgur.com/a/BDK5DYH)! I think I need to use the `scipy.integrate.ode`.

Comment: Replace the signum function by a soft signum like `x/(1e-8+abs(x))`. Then the ODE is continuous and the solver works without doing strange things.

Comment: @LutzL now that was a nice workaround :) thanks a lot. But I think `scipy.integrate.ode` could also be used. It would be great if I could get help for that too.

Comment: Use the more recent `solve_ivp` interfaces. You will not get better results, as the vector field of the ODE is non-continuous and ODE solver with adaptive step sizes rely on continuous derivatives up to the order of the method. This does not matter much if the discontinuity is traversed transversally, but gives catastrophic results if the solution stalls at the curve/surface of discontinuity.

Answer (score 1):

Your system has 3 smooth sub-systems or phases according to the sign of `x'`. As long as the integration stays inside these smooth phases, the step size controller works as expected. At the moment that the phase changes however, the step size controller sees huge changes and oscillations in the quantities that it uses to adapt the step size, requiring to regulate the step size down.

Next comes that the method in `odeint`, `lsode`, is implicit, and that the assumption for the implicit method is that the right side of the equation is again sufficiently differentiable, at least once. Failing that the implicit solver can go anywhere, which you observe in the spike.

---

One solution is to eliminate the discontinuities by continuing each phase beyond their boundaries and use the event mechanism of the ODE solver to find the points where the boundary is crossed. To that end introduce a sign/phase selector parameter `S` and solve the system

```
    m*x''+b*x'+k*x+M*S = F
```

using the function `e(t)=x'(t)` as event function.

```python
# Define differential equation
m,b,k,M,F = 1., 1., 1., 0.1, 1.
def fun(t, x, S):
    dx = [x[1], (F-b*x[1]-k*x[0]-M*S)/m]
    return np.asarray(dx)

# Define event function and make it a terminal event
def event(t, x):
    return x[1]
event.terminal = True

t = 0
x = [1.,2.]; 
S = np.sign(u[1]);
tend = 10
```

As we need to change the phase selector at the event location, the modus of the event has to be `terminal`. Then loop through the phase segments and combine them to a global solution like in the answer of chthonicdaemon to the question "https://stackoverflow.com/q/50701425/3088138".

To get a definitive behavior make sure that at each event the phase boundary is crossed at each event (if the acceleration is non-zero (and it is almost always non-zero)). Note that this construction was selected for its ability to simulate the sliding mode behavior. In the absence of such a cleaner solution is to use the `.direction` flag of the event function to avoid repeating the last event.

```
ts = []
xs = []
eps=1e-8
for _ in range(50):
    sol = solve_ivp(lambda t,u:fun(t,u,S), (t, tend), x, events=event, atol=1e-12, rtol=1e-8, max_step=0.01);
    ts.append(sol.t)
    xs.append(sol.y)
    if sol.status == 1: # Event was hit
        # New start time for integration
        t = sol.t[-1]
        # Reset initial state
        x = sol.y[:, -1].copy()
        # ensure the crossing of the phase boundary
        dx = fun(t,x,S)
        dt = -(eps*S+x[1])/dx[1]; # should be minimal
        if dt > 0: t += dt; x += dt*dx;
        # new phase parameter
        S = np.sign(x[1]);
        # stop the iteration if it stalls 
        if t-sol.t[0] <5e-12: break
    else:
        break
        
# We have to stitch together the separate simulation results for plotting
t=np.concatenate(ts);
x=np.concatenate(xs, axis=1);
```

Then plot the solutions, for instance like below. The integration stalls at `t=4.7880468` with `x=0.9453532`. Around this point on `x'=0` the acceleration is `x''=-0.0453532` for slightly positive `x'` and `x''=0.15464678` for slightly negative `x'` and `x''=0.05464678` on `x'=0`. There is no equilibrium position and no way to proceed forward in time. Due to the forcing to pass through the boundary, in the numerical computation the dynamic can proceed in time, however the smaller the size of `eps`, the amplitude of that oscillation, the smaller the wave length and thus the step size. The last condition in the integration loop finishes (for much smaller `eps`) the integration if the oscillation wave length becomes too small.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. I will read it and will get back soon. I appreciate your kind support.