# Matlab's "OutputFcn" implementation in Python for ODE solving

Tags: python, matlab, ode

I am trying to solve an ODE using Python's solve_ivp. However, I want to change the right hand side of my ODE dynamically based on a comparison between the current solution and previous solution. The idea behind this is that my right hand side is a vector field, and I want to ensure directionality of the vector field by reversing the right hand side based on the direction of the previous solution.

The implementation for this is as follows: I want to check the dot product in the right hand side function definition between the previous solution and the vector field. If the dot product is negative the right hand side is multiplied by -1.

I therefore need to access the previous state of the ODE solver and use it in comparison with the current iteration. In MATLAB there is the possibility of using "OutputFcn" while solving an ODE. This function is called after every iteration of the integrator. In the function it is therefore possible to simply extract the state as a variable and use it in the next iteration. I have not been able to find something similar for Python.

```py
def RHS(timesnotused,x):
    out = solve_ivp(doubleGyreVar, [0,T/2, T], [x[0], x[1], 1, 0, 0, 1], rtol = 1e-10, atol=1e-10)
    output = out.y
    J = output[2:,-1].reshape(2,2)
    CG = np.matmul(J.T , J)
    lambdas, xis = np.linalg.eig(CG)
    xi_1 = xis[np.argmin(lambdas)] 
    xi_2 = xis[np.argmax(lambdas)]
    lambda_1 = np.min(lambdas)
    lambda_2 = np.max(lambdas)

    alpha = ((lambda_2-lambda_1) / (lambda_2+lambda_1))**2

    sign = 1
    if np.dot(xlast,xi_1) < 0:
        sign = -1

    return(sign*alpha*xi_1)
```

As can be seen I want "xlast" to be the previous solution, and check it with xi_1 of the current iteration. Somehow xlast needs to be updated every iteration.

Comment: This is not a very well defined mathematical problem. How likely do you think that your computation is different to the case where you take the current point in the computation of the dot product?

Comment: I am not sure how likely it is, but the method I am trying to use has been executed earlier in Matlab using the "outputfcn" method,

Comment: I'm just saying that this sounds like an XY problem, where you look for a solution to the Y programming problem where it would be better to first gain clarity on the X mathematical modeling problem. Note that the times that outputfcn are called are non-predictable, and not guaranteed to be uniform. They are somewhat related to the curvature of the solution, and of course depending on the tolerances given. In any case what you are doing in the Y implementation is rather unrelated to the X problem and thus the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the differential equation you want to solve is

```
dx/dt = sign(g(x)) * F(x)
```

for some sufficiently smooth functions `g, F`, then you have a discontinuous right side where all advanced numerical solvers will produce nonsense as soon as they approach this jump singularity.

The clearest method to solve such a multi-phase system is to present only continuous right sides to the numerical solver and to handle the phase change via the event mechanism that is also present in `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`.

I explored a mechanism to do that with the tools of `scipy` in a similar problem with a sign function producing a discontinuity in [odeint returns wrong results for an ODE including descrete function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54767096/3088138)