# Equivalent of "OutputFcn" of matlab in Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, ode

[image: Incorrect plot]Like MATLAB ODE solvers have `Outputfcn` where the ODE solver calls the function after every successful time step

```
options=odeset('OutputFcn',@odeprint)
    [T,Y]=ode15s(@(T,X)sys(T,X,vin),[t0 .0005],X(:,1),options)
```

Is there any equivalent output function in scipy's solve_ivp which is called after every time step to store the solution vector?
Or is there any way to create this output function in scipy's solve_ivp?

For my code:
Defining A,R as `4*4` and B,S as `4*1
Z as`4*1`

```
def func(t,Z):
  if  X[0]>5 or X[1]>0:
      Zdot=A*Z+B*U
  else:
      Zdot=R*Z+S*U
return Zdot

sol = solve_ivp(func, tspan,Z0)
aa=sol.t
bb=sol.y
X=v1.dot(bb)[:][i]
plt.plot(aa,X[0,:],'r')
```

I'm having a problem in defining  `X=v1.dot(bb)[:][i]` because I don't know the length of `bb` beforehand.This is what I want to do.This code doesn't work though.At every time step of the solver, I want `X` as 4*1 array using `X=v1.dot(bb)` where v1 is another matrix of 4*4

Comment: The `events` parameter appears to accept functions (but I haven't used it).   Presumably you can read the docs as well as any of us.

Comment: But I don't want any event detection in my program. Output function of MATLAB stores all successful solutions that can be accessed during the program for evaluation of the next successful step. I want the same thing in scipy.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not give an `t_eval` option, the solution structure contains in the `.t` and `.y` fields the inner step points. If you pass the option `dense_output=True`, then the solution structure contains in `.sol` a piecewise polynomial interpolation function that you can use to get the solution at any other time or or list of times.

If you want more control you probably will need to use the underlying stepper classes for the integration method directly.

---

If you want to switch models `y'=f_1(y)` and `y'=f_2(y)` along some surface `g(y)=0`, then you can in principle use

```py
def odefun(t,y):
    return f_1(y) if g(y)>0 else f_2(y);
```

But the solver will react very badly to this, possibly even give out warnings about a dangerously low step size while crossing the phase boundaries. A better way is to use a switching variable if the models are similar enough or just switch out the functions and use the event mechanism to find the exact time of a phase change.

```
def event(t,y): x=v.dot(y); return max(x[0]-5,x[1]) 

event.terminal=True
event.direction = -1 if event(t0,y0)>0 else 1
```

and then inside the loop after each event switch the sign of the direction and select the correct function

```
event.direction *=-1
odefun = f_1 if event.direction<0 else f_2
```

Then add code to the loop to append the last solution to the previously collected solution data, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54796425/3088138 for a possible solution.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212787/discussion-on-answer-by-lutz-lehmann-equivalent-of-outputfcn-of-matlab-in-scip).