# Altering output of solve_ivp for given input

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I have a bit of a simple question regarding solving a differential equation I'm hoping someone can help me answer. I have a differential equation for a simple neuron model, with varying input (i.e. integrate and fire model of a neuron, with a "square" input):

```py
def impulse_func(t, V):
    if 100 <= t <= 200:
        return 0.25
    return 0

def passive_membrane(t, V, El, R, tau, I_app):
    dVdt = (-(V - El) + R*I_app(t, V))/tau     
    return dVdt

t = np.arange(0, 400, 0.1)
V0 = np.array([-60.])

V = solve_ivp(fun = passive_membrane,
              t_span = [0, 400], 
              t_eval = t, 
              y0=V0, 
              args = (-60., 100., 10., impulse_func),
              dense_output=True, 
              rtol = 1e-8, atol = 1e-8)
```

In this case, the values of El, R, and tau will be remaining constant. This works just as expected, with the plot being[image: it goes here] My problem is that I now need to create a "spike" in the solution which is dependent on the solution.

Specifically, if the solution passes my "threshold" value of -37, for a single unit of time I would like to set the solution value to 60 and then return to my "resting" which is -65 in the next unit of time. I've tried modifying the `impulse_func` and the `passive_membrane` functions, but it just led to an exploding solution. I'm able to do this when I write my own solver, but I'm lost on how to implement it with `solve_ivp`, which I'd like to use since it has much more functionality than my own poorly optimized RK2 method and because I want to be able to pass variable thresholds, times, etc.

Comment: * What is a "unit of time" here? // * At level 65, and the jumps to and from it, is the differential equation switched off? Or do you just want to manipulate the equilibrium positions? // * What you describe sounds like an event-action mechanism that is not implemented in scipy. You can find such a thing for instance in the julia-lang diffeq package, the R-lang desolve module has similar. Here you would have to work with terminal events and restarting the solver in the new modus after manually performing the desired action.

Comment: You could also try to adapt your existing RK2 loop to work with the RK45 stepper class (or any other) that is behind `method='RK45'` of `solve_ivp` and use its "dense output" interpolation to translate from the internal adaptive time-stepping to the fixed-rate sampling for the external result.

Comment: @LutzLehmann hey! So in this case a unit of time would be one millisecond. My simulation here runs for 400 milliseconds with a resolution of 0.1 (I should have included the units, my apologies). And I've tried to understand event-action mechanisms, but I thought solve_ivp does that? In any case, do you have an example of how I'd adapt a solver to work with the solve_ivp? It sounds interesting but prelim googling doesn't show me anything

Comment: No, solve_ivp only has an event mechanism, it has no implementation for action callback procedures. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767096/odeint-returns-wrong-results-for-an-ode on how a solution for a system with jumps can be implemented, here the action is the change of the sign (of) `S`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann wonderful, thanks so much for the help. I'll update with a proper solution to my question when I get there.